# Connecting to domain registry EPP server

Tags: xml, ssl, epp

I'm getting my sea legs and need some pointers and a small sample of code that connects to an epp server. The sample of code need to login and send one command and receive a response.(in XML). 
Code can be in php or python.

This I believe will form a basis/kickstart for me to delve in further and learn more about this topic. It's driving me up the wall - in a good way as I want to solve it in one day or a thousand.

And I have been searching for days now but can't seem to make sense of the info found, and 
now opted to ask here for guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Originally posted by the asker as an answer: "It took a while but I found the kickstart I wanted. Now I'll get busy. It seems information in this area is hard to come by. Anyway persistence always wins."

Answer (score 1):

This is sample php script

```
<?php


class Epp 
{

var $socket;

public function __construct()
{
}


private $_connected = false;

function connect($host, $port = 700, $timeout = 1, $ssl = true)
{
    if ($this->_connected)
        return true;
    $target = sprintf('%s://%s', ($ssl === true ? 'ssl' : 'tcp'), $host);
    $socket = fsockopen($target, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if (!$socket) {
        return new PEAR_Error("Error connecting to $target: $errstr (code $errno)");
    } else {
        $this->socket = $socket;
        $this->_connected = true;
        return $this->getFrame();
    }
}


function getFrame()
{
    if (feof($this->socket))
        return new PEAR_Error("Connection appears to have closed.");
    $hdr = @fread($this->socket, 4);
    if (empty($hdr)) {
        return new PEAR_Error("Error reading from server: $php_errormsg");
    } else {
        $unpacked = unpack('N', $hdr);
        $answer = fread($this->socket, ($unpacked[1] - 4));
        return $answer;
    }
}

function sendFrame($xml)
{
    return @fwrite($this->socket, pack('N', (strlen($xml) + 4)) . $xml);
}

function disconnect()
{
    return @fclose($this->socket);
}

}

?>
```

And there are 4 functions , connect , getFrame , sendFrame , disconnect .
Epp protocol works following .
Firstly you must connect to server .

Send xml request to server and receive xml response from server .

And firstly you must login to server . for that you must send login xml to server .

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0
      epp-1.0.xsd">
    <command>
        <login>
            <clID><?php echo $username;?></clID>
            <pw><?php echo $password;?></pw>
            <options>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <lang>en</lang>
            </options>
            <svcs>
                <svcExtension>

                </svcExtension>
            </svcs>
        </login>
        <clTRID>12345</clTRID>
    </command>
</epp>
```

All request and responses is xml . And you can find xmls from this sites
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5732